# Wordpress ad_filter to title

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

i have problem to ad tiitle to title :P

I just have created custom post type. Now i want Get random title from element from custom post type and write it after POST (standard post) here is my code:

```
function pobierajslowa() {
        $args=array(
              'orderby' => rand,
              'post_type' => 'slowa_kluczowe_wpisu',
              'posts_per_page' => 1,
              'caller_get_posts'=> 1
            );
            $queryObject = new WP_Query($args);
            while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
                $queryObject->the_post();
                return get_the_title(); 
            }
}


function theme_slug_filter_the_content( $title ) {
    $custom_content = $title;
    $custom_content .= ' '.pobierajslowa().'';
    return $custom_content;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
```

After when i use this, i get 503 error :O What i have do wrong?

Comment: This is unrelated...but I recommend you add an `else` in case there are no `slowa_kluczowe_wpisu` posts...

Answer (score 1):

```
'orderby' => rand,
```

Should be...

```
'orderby' => 'rand',  // a string
```

Make sure to double check syntax. Turning on [`WP_Debug`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) should tell you where the issues are.